# Cannot display ArrayList<String> within android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to display simple text I retrieve from a URL.  This code works fine if I run it using `System.out.println()` to the java console, but when I change to Android, no text is displayed.  Since I can get text to display if I hard code a string in `setText`, I assume my problem is in `ArrayList`.  Thank you in advance for your help.

`onCreate`

```
try {

    ArrayList<String> myData = new ArrayList<String>();
    LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView myText = new TextView(this);

    BufferedReader br = null;       
    URL url;

    url = new URL("URL to plain text");
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        myData.add(inputLine);
    }

    br.close();

    myText.setText(myData.get(1));
    lView.addView(myText);
    setContentView(lView);


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Try setting the text after you added it to the view.

Comment: I hope this is prototype code, otherwise please seperate at least UI and file IO.

Comment: `myText.setText(myData.get(1));` can't do that on a background thread.

Comment: and you know for a fact that `myData.get(1)` contains something because you logged it?

Comment: Probably there is a NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: Yes, this is just prototype code to help me learn android deveopment.I'm sure myData.get(1) contains info.

Answer (score 1):

Do it that way:

```
myText.setText(Arrays.toString(myData.toArray(new String[myData.size()])));
```

It'll print the whole contents of *myData*.

Comment: not relevant to the question. the question is not the get the content of `myData`, as logging to sysout apparently works.

Comment: @njzk2 I can't say, if *myData.get(1)* is not an empty String. So it might help to solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for that comment Denis. It is relevant to the question that I have. Ironically @njzk2 made a snarky comment on my question as well.